# Have a variable name in Excel hold a value but display a string

Tags: excel

There may be a trick to do this but in playing around with it, I have so far not been successful.

I want to add up a bunch of numbers, (1,2,4,3,7), but also want to have a string displayed (var1) that holds the value 10. So if I were to sum each table cell including (1,2,4,3,7,var1), it would equal 27 and not 17.

I would like to be able to see var1 on the spreadsheet in addition to the sum of 27 (result of `=SUM(G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6)` where G6 holds the string value `var1` and `G1-G5` hold integers.

Comment: ... I don't understand what you are asking - Can you clarify your question - Based upon your question, you could just define `Dim Var1 as Integer` and you're done...

Comment: Could you explain that in terms of how it would be set up in Excel? It may be that easy.

Comment: I think you need to use named regions.

Comment: This is a fairly difficult solution using only Excel, but fairly easy to fix using VBA - I could explain to you how to do it if you're willing to go that way - Let me know...

Comment: Does it require installing/using additional software or is it all from within Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Though not a solution to the question, I resolved my problem by using a custom format: # "[var1]" which displays the text I want while also having a integer value. The number is still visible however so I am still looking for the real solution.